# OBD several errors big picture

Tags: engine, obd-ii, mitsubishi, proton

I have a proton wira 2004 which is essentially a Mitsubishi Colt, I got these errors when I connected an OBD2 device.
Could anyone tell me the big picture, what do they mean combined?

Thanks in advance.

[image: OBD errors]

Comment: There’s not enough data here. Can you provide freeze frame data? Which engine does the car have? Do you have wiring diagrams for the car? The ECT and IAT sensors may share an engine ground or they could use a common low reference circuit. Are these current, pending or history dtcs? What does the live data show? Do a visual inspection. Is anything obviously wrong?

Comment: Well, as pointed out some could be historical so personally, I would clear them all and then see which, if any, return. Then take action...

Comment: How long has the check engine light been on and are there any engine performance symptoms?

Comment: Its a Mitsubishi 4g13 engine with fuel injection.

Comment: The car has lower fuel efficiency and lower power with occasional hoccups

Comment: Was the check engine light on before the symptoms started?

Comment: Yes I believe it was, I think the errors are related to my problems